# Displaying parent record with child records below

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to join a parent table and child table and then display the results in the following manner:

Parent

- Child a
- Child b
- Child c

Parent #2

- Child 2a
- Child 2b

They have a common column sub_id. The child table also has a `sub_id`_number with is basically the sub_id with a -01,-02,-03, etc. attached to it. So 12345-01, 12345-02, etc.

I can get the records to display, but the parent always display with each child record, instead of listing all of the child records below the correct parent record.

I'm using mysqli and php to display.

It seems like there should be a foreach in there, but I'm so lost, I'm not sure anymore.

Comment: When you say "display" do you mean "convert to HTML"?

Comment: Yes, I'd use PHP to display it as html.

Comment: Alright, so you've got an idea of what you're doing. What would you do first? There's no effort to solve the problem demonstrated here.